# Serilog error when deployed to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, serilog

I have Serilog working perfectly when running locally in IIS/Visual Studio (.netCore 3.1), but when I deploy it to AWS Lambda the application fails to start and I am getting the following error in the CloudWatch logs:

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Serilog.Extensions.Hosting.DiagnosticContext' while attempting to activate 'Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware

Any ideas what this means or how to go about solving it?

edited to show code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting up");

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Comment: Apologies, tag removed

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Serilog.Extensions.Hosting.DiagnosticContext' while attempting to activate 'Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642991/serilog-extensions-hosting-diagnosticcontext-while-attempting-to-activate-ser)? If no then please provide more code to show how you configure application.

Comment: As far as I can see my code matches what is in that link. I've edited my question to show my code

Comment: That post said to use ```.UseSerilog()```