# Unable to resolve service for'Serilog.Extensions.Hosting.DiagnosticContext' while attempting to activate 'Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware, .net-5, serilog

I get the following exception when I want to use Custom `SerilogRequestLogging` as a middleware:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Serilog.Extensions.Hosting.DiagnosticContext' while attempting to
> activate 'Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware'.

My Custom SerilogRequestLogging in external Library:

```
   public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomSerilogRequestLogging(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
                return app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(options =>
                   {
                       options.EnrichDiagnosticContext = (diagnosticContext, httpContext) =>
                       {

                           diagnosticContext.Set("RequestHost", httpContext.Request.Host.Value);
                           diagnosticContext.Set("RequestScheme", httpContext.Request.Scheme);
                           diagnosticContext.Set("RequestMethod", httpContext.Request.Method);
                           diagnosticContext.Set("RequestProtocol", httpContext.Request.Protocol);
                           diagnosticContext.Set("RequestPath", httpContext.Request.Path);
                           diagnosticContext.Set("RequestRemoteAddress", httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress);

                       };
                   });
        }
```

---

Then I add it as a middleware in Configure method like this:

```
 app.UseCustomSerilogRequestLogging();
```

---

In program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseSerilog((provider, context, loggerConfig) =>
                {
                    loggerConfig.Configure(provider, Configuration);
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

---

The extension method in external Library:

```
public static void Configure(this LoggerConfiguration loggerConfig,
        IServiceProvider provider, IConfiguration config)
        {
            var sqlserverConnectionString = config["ConnectionStrings:S1"];
            var sqlserverLogTable = config["Logging:S2"];
            var rollingFileName = config["Logging:S3"];

            //SQL CONFIGURATION HERE TO REDUCE THE NUMBER OF LINES...

            loggerConfig
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .Enrich.WithAssemblyName()
            .Enrich.WithAssemblyVersion()
            .WriteTo.File(rollingFileName, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .WriteTo.Seq(seqAddress)
           .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                connectionString: sqlserverConnectionString,
                sinkOptions: sinkOpts,
                columnOptions: columnOpts
            );
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Serilog.Extensions.Hosting.DiagnosticContext' while attempting to activate 'Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642991/serilog-extensions-hosting-diagnosticcontext-while-attempting-to-activate-ser)

Comment: @JuanR  No, this's the first thing I found after searching and because the answer suggests using .UseSerilog and I already use it so this doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare your currently shown examples do not show you using `.UseSerilog()` with the main host builder. While you may have added to the application builder, based on the exception, it was not added to the service collection, which is what resolves the dependencies

Comment: @Nkosi :`webBuilder.UseSerilog((provider, context, loggerConfig)`

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare check linked provided answer again and note where they are calling `.UseSeriLog()`

Comment: @Nkosi I call it in `CreateHostBuilder` in `Program.cs`  typically like the answer.

Comment: @Nkosi Could U help me to detect the difference please

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare You call UseSerilog on the web host where as the link answer also calls it on the default host.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare I would also suggest if calling it on the web host that you do it before calling `UseStartup`

Comment: @Nkosi : I have updated my question, and based on you suggestion, I have called it before calling `UseStartup` but I face the same problem.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseSerilog().ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>.....`

Comment: @Nkosi But how to access the parameters `(provider, context, loggerConfig)` in this case

Comment: What I suggested is in addition to what you currently have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your currently shown examples do not show you using `.UseSerilog()` with the main host builder. While you may have added to the web default builder, based on the exception, it was not added to the service collection, which is what resolves the dependencies when the host is eventually built.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog() //<-- THIS WAS MISSING HERE
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
            webBuilder.UseSerilog((provider, context, loggerConfig) => {
                loggerConfig.Configure(provider, Configuration);
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Everything else remains the same.

Reference [Serilog.Extensions.Hosting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting#serilogextensionshosting--)

Comment: Thank U so much, I was confused because here U have called the `UseSerilog` twice

Comment: Have a look at source code here for `UseSerilog()` extension on host builder https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Extensions.Hosting/SerilogHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L28 if you look at the `ConfigureServices` method within you will see where they add the missing context

Comment: I'm really grateful